# Is a Bei'ur the same thing as a Peirush?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, jewish-books, torah-study, parshanut-theory

What characteristics define Biur and Peirush? Are they different from one another?  Are they related somehow? If so, in which aspects? Please, explain. Sources are welcome.

Comment: Beur is extended paraphrase, perush is a sum of punctually explanations

Comment: See Baer heytev in Gemara Sotah, that regards translation of the tora in 70 languages

Comment: Technically, they are "clarification" and "interpretation", but they were/are used interchangeably without a clear distinction.

Comment: I find that ביאור is used in something that explains the source, such as ביאור הלכה and ביאור הגר"א.  While פירוש is usually used when just bringing the bottom line of what something means without the sources, such as פירוש המשניות or פירוש רש"י.

Comment: Note Bi'ur with a Chirik means ~"destruction" (like Bi'ur Chametz) and Bei'ur with a Tzere means ~"explanation" (like Bei'ur haGra)

Comment: To Al Berko and Kouty: these are my impression too. My question is: Are there clear definitions (with sources, if any) to this?

Comment: @פריזהב, Perhaps elaborating more would qualify as an answer.

Comment: @RenatoGrun - I don't have proof or a source for this, it's just the way I understand it. So I"m not sure it qualifies as an answer.